# How to display data in text view?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

Hello everyone I'm working on my Android project, I created my expandable list view with Men's and Women's sports, and under each of them list of sports. Next what I have to do is to display data in each sport in textview format. I used intent to get my new activity for each sport and putExtra to display my data with events. Something is wrong in my code and does not want to display any data. I'm new in android world and if someone can help me with this I would really appreciate! Here is my Main.java code:

```
public class MainActivity<View> extends ActionBarActivity {

    ExpandableListView exv;
    List<GroupedFeed> gfList;
    GroupedFeed gfResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        exv=(ExpandableListView)findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
        exv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
        exv.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
        // Here I wanted to create my for loop but that did not work 

        private GroupedFeed findFeed(String locateSport){ 
                if ((!gfList.isEmpty())){
                   gfResult = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i != gfList.size();i++){
                        if (gfList.get(i).category.equalsIgnoreCase(locateSport)){
                           gfResult =  gfList.get(i);
                        }

                    }
                   return gfResult;
                 }
                return null;
               }

            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,
                    android.view.View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                    long id) {
                switch (groupPosition)
                {
                case 0:
                        switch (childPosition)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            gfResult = findFeed("Men's Baseball");
                            Baseball(gfResult);
                              // pass gfResult
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            gfResult =findFeed("Men's Basketball");
                            MensBasketball(gfResult);
                            break;
                       }
                return false;
            }

            private void Baseball(GroupedFeed gfResult) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Baseball.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("Men's Baseball", gfResult);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }

            private void MensBasketball(GroupedFeed gfResult) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MensBasketball.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("Men's Basketball", gfResult);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
```

And here I have my Activity(Baseball) code:

```
public class Baseball extends ActionBarActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.baseball_activity);
        setupBackButton();     
    }

    private void setupBackButton(){
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}

THANKS IN ADVANCE!
```

MyAdapter code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context context;
Typeface typeface;

static String []parentList = {"Men's Sports","Women's Sports"};
static String [][]childList = {
    {
        "Baseball", "Basketball", "Bowling", "Cross Country", "Golf", "Soccer", "Track & Field"
    },
    {
        "Basketball", "Bowling", "Cross Country", "Golf", "Soccer", "Softball", "Track & Field", "Volleyball"
    }
};

    public MyAdapter(Context context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return parentList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childList[groupPosition].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Timeline.ttf");
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(parentList[groupPosition]);
        tv.setPadding(45, 10, 10, 10);
        tv.setTextSize(15);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#003767"));
        tv.setTypeface(typeface);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCCCCC"));
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        typeface=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/Timeline.ttf");
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(childList[groupPosition][childPosition]);
        tv.setPadding(45, 10, 10, 10);
        tv.setTextSize(12);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFDD00"));
        tv.setTypeface(typeface);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#003767"));
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by the following... `MainActivity<View>`? Also, binding data to child list items and list header items in an `ExpandableListView` is done through the adapters but you haven't shown any adapter code.

Comment: I made a mistake by putting <View> that is not necessary, also I updated my question and there is Adapter code.

Comment: So what happens? Is your `ExpandableListView` actually showing with the correct groups and children? Where/when is your code failing?

Comment: My code doe not want to show data in textview. Example: If I click Men's sports then Baseball nothing shows up. I have to get events for Baseball in text view. I think that my Intent does not work properly and  I missing some code inside of Baseball activity.

Comment: I can't see anywhere that you initialise `gfList` which suggests  the line `if ((!gfList.isEmpty()))` would throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Thanks, should I have getIntent under my  Baseball activity?

Comment: Well yes - you're putting an extra into the `Intent` used to start the `Activity` so you need to use `getIntent` in order to retrieve the extra. You'll also need to use `findViewById` to find the `TextView` to display your text.

Comment: Can you provide a code please? I tried already but did not work for me.